# Angular can't resolve parameters during test runs

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm working on an Ionic project with Angular 5.2.5, trying to build a test setup with Jasmine and Karma (orienting on [this example](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-unit-testing-example), which older versions though).

For an already existing and (in manual tests) properly working component `LoginComponent`, I've created the following test:

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AuthenticationProvider } from '../../providers/authentication/authentication';
import { IonicModule, ToastController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginComponent } from './login';

describe('LoginComponent', () => {

  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        LoginComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(LoginComponent),
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: AuthenticationProvider, useValue: {} as AuthenticationProvider },
        { provide: ViewController, useValue: {} as ViewController },
        { provide: ToastController, useValue: {} as ToastController },
      ]
    })
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create component', () => expect(component).toBeDefined())
});
```

Component to be tested:

```js
import { Credentials } from '../../model/credentials';
import { AuthenticationProvider } from '../../providers/authentication/authentication';
import { ViewController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {

  public registration = false;
  public readonly credentials = new Credentials('', '');

  constructor(
    private authentication: AuthenticationProvider,
    private view: ViewController,
    private toast: ToastController,
  ) {
  }

  // (methods omitted for brevity)
}
```

After starting Karma, compilation works and the test is triggered. Then, it fails at runtime with the following error message:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LoginComponent: (?, ?, ?).
    at syntaxError (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:485:21 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:72827:34)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:15700:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:88042:35)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:15535:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:87877:26)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:15020:0 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:87362:24)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:15848:25 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:88190:45)
    at webpack:///node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:15829:29 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:88171:48
[...]
```

To me, this sounds like dependency injection for constructor parameters is failing. But I've listed corresponding providers for all those types in my test module configuration, so those should be used if I'm not mistaken.

What am I missing?

*And for what it's worth, is there a way to make Angular report more details about the error, e.g. which parameters in particular can't be resolved?*

---

#### Update

Additional tempering has shown that even each one of the parameters separately cannot be found. That is, even if the constructor is just

```js
constructor(private toast: ToastController) { }
```

the same error occurs (but with just one question mark for one unresolved parameter). Since ToastController is an ionic-angular built-in, circular dependency issues can probably be ruled out.

---

#### Update 2

Debugging shows that the problem is not on the side of registered providers, but the parameter types cannot be determined in the first place.

At some point in the JIT compiler, the following snippet produces `[undefined]`, corresponding to the one parameter mentioned above (toast):

```
this._reflector.parameters(typeOrFunc)
```

It looks like type information somehow gets lost during compilation.

Comment: In the Component, where is "Credentials" coming from in the line ```new Credentials('', '') ``` I can't see it being declared anywhere.

Comment: @Fewster Oh, it's being imported, I accidentally cropped the import line out when pasting. But I guess it shouldn't be relevant in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix the issue.

There was an (unused) import in my `karma-test-shim.js` (a helper to load angular testing code and initialize the test environment):

```
import { AppModule } from '../src/app/app.module';
```

Removing it finally made my test green.

*Frankly, it's beyond me why this broke dependency injection, or how it's related to the error message and my debug findings.*

Answer (score 0):

Can you trying doing something like this and write in the comments if it's working or not?

```
class AuthenticationProviderMock extends AuthenticationProvider {}
class ViewControllerMock extends ViewController {}
class ToastControllerMock extends ToastController {}

providers: [
        { provide: AuthenticationProvider, useClass: AuthenticationProviderMock },
        { provide: ViewController, useClass: ViewControllerMock },
        { provide: ToastController, useClass: ToastControllerMock },
      ]
```

Comment: The same error is reported. It seems like those providers are not picked up by Angular at all.